# How can I assign data to an element id in angular.js vs. jquery

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use something to attach data to an element id. In jquery its as such `$('#tree').treeview({data: dataValue});` How is something like this approached? I attempted `ng-bind` and `ng-model` am I on the right track?

Index code
`<div ng-model="tree"></div>`

Controller code

```
$scope.tree = [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 3"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 4"
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 5"
  }
];
```

Comment: Why do you need to attach data to an element? What does that mean to you?

Comment: It means the json my server is sending back to me I need to bind it to the `<div id="tree"></div>`

Comment: This has X/Y problem written all over it. Perhaps you're looking for this? http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

Comment: try to use `ng-repeat`

Comment: Doesn't $('#tree').treeview({}) call a function using jquery sauce?

Comment: can you plz paste all the codes in jsfiddle.net and give the link...i mean the complete html and controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular, you have $scope.

Assigning data to an element is as easy as assigning data to a model that resides on $scope.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
   {{ value }}
</div>
```

Script

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'hello world!';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either. The `ng-model` is used whenever your doing two-way binding (form inputs).

And this would be used instead of the `id="tree"`.  It would just be `ng-model="tree"`.

Then in the controller you can say:

```
$scope.tree = '';
```

And whatever the user inputs will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i am attaching data to a table from a data array in `contactlist` is the data array from the js file and as i have used `ng-repeat` i donot need to make three rows even as there are 3 elements in the data array

```
<tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
```